# Windows Phone 8 (C++ Only) - Possible to access device manufacturer?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

Currently developing a Windows Phone 8 application in pure C++/Direct3D. We now need to access the Device Manufacturer name but it seems to only be available under C# which, according to my research is not accessible from this type of application.

This page lists some of the calls I would like to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus(v=vs.105).aspx.

```
// If only I could call this line from C++
DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer;
```

Is there anyway to get this information without having to refactor the app as a XAML/C++ hybrid application which allows the base app to be C#.

Comment: Indeed I don't think you can: I can't see it in the list of available WinRT calls on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207212(v=vs.105).aspx. Might be one to flag on http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform.

Answer (score 1):

Not in Pure C++/Direct3D but if you would have used the Direct3D with Xaml project template, you would have been able to.