# How getting hardware information in windows-phone8 in c++?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

I have an app on Windows Phone 8, which is pure c++.
I want getting information about device; for example the deviceid, manufacturer, and MAC address.

For c# there is a link :

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

but how do I get this information in c++?

Comment: This is a very common question for any platform.  Having the tools and having completely no idea for a project to use them.  Getting an answer isn't going to help your user, he just wants to play a game.  Humor him, you can get Hangman going.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get very intimate with [Win32 and COM API for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207198%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Especially [Supported Win32 APIs for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Dig down and you will find various API's scattered all over the place.

Its back to win32 programming for you!

You also need to learn the [Windows Phone Runtime API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207212%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Ahh .. I just found another SO question [Windows Phone 8 (C++ Only) - Possible to access device manufacturer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833882/windows-phone-8-c-only-possible-to-access-device-manufacturer)

So I think you may be out of luck with the device Info

Comment: But win32 for winphone 8 is a small subset of older win32. and many functions are not existed for winphone. i dont find function for my task in list of wupported win32 in winphone/